# I can't access localhost in Android

Tags: android, apache, localhost

I setup a localhost and it works fine on macos sierra.

```
localhost/~username
```

But now I'm trying to acces from Chrome Browser on my Android

```
192.168.x.x/~username
```

and got this message.

```
Forbidden. You don't have permission to access /~username from this server
```

My phone and mac are connected to the same wifi.

And also edit the httpd.conf

```
<Directory />
   AllowOverride All
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And it´s not working.

Answer (score 0):

open your terminal and type this command :

```
chmod 777 parent_directory/localhost
```

Comment: i tried and doesn't work, the directory is this  "/Users/username/Sites/"